# Pass received argument to a callback function

Tags: c, function, callback, arguments, gtk

I am working on a Gtk project in C.

From the main.c I call a **function1** with an int address as a parameter.

In that **function1**, I can access that first value, but then at the end (inside) of that **function1**, I call another **function2** (which is a callback function to a click event) and pass it the address I got from the **function1** parameter.

But in **function2**, the address have changed, definitely can't figure out **why**...

My project looks like this :

**[main.c]**

```
int main(...) {

    int a = 50;
    function1(&a);

}
```

**[function1.c]**

```
void function1(int* nb) {
    ...
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button),"clicked", G_CALLBACK(function2), &nb);
    // I know that the 4th arg expects void*, but even though I give the address of that _nb_ parameter, still can't get that 50 in function2
}
```

**[function2.c]**

```
void function2(void* nb) {
    ...
    printf("should got 50 : %d ", *(int*)nb);
    // shows random 8 digits number like 60035152
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that each function is in a separate file, I don't know if that matters as long as I do the includes and gives the prototypes...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Pass in `nb` instead of `&nb`.

Comment: You're passing the address of a local variable. That address becomes invalid when the function returns.

Comment: So in function1, in the g_signal_connect, i passed nb but it still don't give me that 50 in function2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's in your code are:-

1) you are passing the address of the variable to the callback function 
    so instead of &nb, it should be nb.

2) this is the callback function for clicked signal (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked_

```
void
user_function (GtkButton *button,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

you are missing an argument in your callback function

Comment:  Oh. My. Goodness. Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

First, you're passing the address of a local variable, but this cannot be used after the function returns.

Second, `function2` expects `nb` to be a pointer to `int`, but you're passing a pointer to a pointer to `int` to `g_signal_connect()`.

```
void function1(int* nb) {
    ...
    int *nb_copy = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *nb_copy = *nb;
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button),"clicked", G_CALLBACK(function2), nb_copy);
    // I know that the 4th arg expects void*, but even though I give the address of that _nb_ parameter, still can't get that 50 in function2
}
```

`function_2()` should `free(nb);` after it's done with it to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking the time to answer, I tried your solution but it still shows me a bunch of random digits, am I right to have the following for function2 : ```function2(void* nb) {...``` ? Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you should use `GINT_TO_POINTER`?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that Im going to try it out Thanks !