# The difference between using GtkFileChooserButton and GtkFileChooserDialog

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I would like to let user choose two directories and then retrieve their URIs after the click of button so I could pass them to another function. For now I have tried to do something along of:

```
directory1 = gtk_file_chooser_button_new ("Choose directory 1",GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
```

The same for directory2. Then put them inside struct

```
struct directories {
    GtkWidget *first;
    GtkWidget *second;
};

struct directories directory;
    directory.first = directory1;
    directory.second = directory2;
```

And after the click of a button pass it to function which currently does nothing but tries to retrieve URIs and print them.

```
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_test), &directory);

print_test (struct directories *dirc)
{
    g_print("%s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dirc->first)));
    g_print("%s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dirc->second)));
}
```

I have also tried replacing `GTK_FILE_CHOOSER` with `GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_BUTTON` but the result is the same: my program is compiled, I choose some directories and after activating the button it crashes having printed one

> (null)

and the following debug info

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 02:52:03.786: invalid uninstantiatable type 'gchararray' in cast to 'GtkFileChooserButton'
Gtk-CRITICAL **: 02:52:03.786: gtk_file_chooser_get_uri: assertion 'GTK_IS_FILE_CHOOSER (chooser)' failed
```

I thought that gtk_file_chooser_button was a good solution because it seemed simpler to use than to manually establish dialog but now I started to question whether I am allowed to use it that way or is the failure of my program the fault of wrong method of passing pointers to the *print_test*. Unfortunately all the examples I found focus on using dialogs so I did not find a good example from which I could learn how to use gtk_file_chooser_button.

EDIT: Per request I present my code sample. I only removed other types of buttons which are not a matter of this question AND performed changes described in the first comment thus you can observe minor differences in two lines compared to the question above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct directories {
    GtkWidget *first;
    GtkWidget *second;
};

static void
print_test (GtkWidget *somewidget, struct directories *dirc)
{
    g_print("%s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dirc->first)));
    g_print("%s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dirc->second)));
}

static void
set_expand (GtkWidget *widget)
{
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(widget, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(widget, 1);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *frame;
    GtkWidget *settings;
    GtkWidget *directory1;
    GtkWidget *directory2;
    GtkWidget *button;

    //Prepare the window
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Sagger");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 200);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    //Prepare the grid
    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    //gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(grid, 1);
    //gtk_widget_set_halign (grid, GTK_ALIGN_FILL);
    //gtk_widget_set_valign (grid, GTK_ALIGN_FILL);
    set_expand(grid);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);

    //Prepare directory chooser
    settings = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    frame = gtk_frame_new("Choose directories");
    set_expand(settings);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame), settings);
    directory1 = gtk_file_chooser_button_new ("Source directory",GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    set_expand(directory1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(settings), directory1);
    directory2 = gtk_file_chooser_button_new ("Target directory",GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    set_expand(directory2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(settings), directory2);
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, frame, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    //Prepare the run button
    settings = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_button_box_set_layout(GTK_BUTTON_BOX(settings), GTK_BUTTONBOX_EXPAND);
    set_expand(settings);
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, settings, 0, 2, 2, 1);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("RUN");

    //Try to pass the chosen directories
    struct directories directory;
    directory.first = directory1;
    directory.second = directory2;
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_test), (gpointer) &directory);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(settings), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("pl.etua.sagger", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Try and post a full self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: your callback function is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473619/pass-received-argument-to-a-callback-function/59480752#59480752

Comment: @SivaGuru Thank you, I added an argument to the print_test `print_test (GtkWidget *somewidget, struct directories *dirc)` and I tweaked _g signal connect_ `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_test), &directory);` but I don't know what to do next as currently I get SIGSEGV after the click of a button but it is impossible to compile the program with `directory` or `(gpointer) directory` in place of `&directory` and the `(gpointer) &directory` also results in SIGSEGV. I understand that what I do there is basically guessing but I have no other idea for what to put there.

Comment: @mnistic I added it below my question

Comment: This is a memory management issue, try making `struct directories directory` global. The problem is with making it local to the activate function.

Comment: By a closer inspection, you have to make it local because the activate function can be called many times and each time you need a different struct. So you have to allocate the struct on the heap by using malloc() and free(), or g_new0() and g_free().

Comment: @lb90 Why do you think that `activate()` is called more than once here?

Comment: Hi! activate() is not for program initialization at startup, it is meant to react to invocations of the program. [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/GtkApplication/) has a built-in IPC mechanism to ensure having a single process, like for example the browsers do. If you execute the program and it detects that an instance is already running, it will signal the primary instance trough IPC and terminate. Then the primary instance will execute the 'activate' callback.

Comment: To make it short: if you launch two instances of the program, you will see two windows, but only one process. The activate() callback has been executed two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`directory` is local to the `activate()` function, and, as mentioned in the comments, will get destroyed when it goes out of scope. Later on, when the `print_test()` function is invoked on button click, it will try to access this memory, leading to the segmentation fault.

Two easy ways out:

Make `directory` global:

```
struct directories {
    GtkWidget *first;
    GtkWidget *second;
};
struct directories directory;
```

Or make it static in `activate()`:

```
static struct directories directory;
```

Comment: Making the struct static did the job. Adding that change to the code given at the bottom allowed it to perform correctly. Do you agree with the concern about the first solution expressed by lb90 or should they both work in the same way?

Comment: I would actually recommend making the object global for readability. lb90's concern does not make sense to me, `activate()` should be called only once...